# How can I offer two different packages of a product with two different prices in Magneto?

Tags: magento

I wish to offer an item for sale as two different packages. Package 1 will be the product by itself and Package 2 will be the product with a free gift. How do I do this in Magento?

Comment: i guess u see the title very clear !!! that i want to do like already done on this site, how to add a product such that with two different prices and different packages ????

Comment: @shame: you're right, but I realized late, sorry.

Comment: its ok :) any suggestions or solution ???

Comment: Please don't ask questions like "How do I do what this website is doing:  SomeSpammyWebsiteIWantToDriveTrafficTo.com?"  It makes you look like a spammer that wants to drive traffic to your spammy website.  If applicable, you can take a screenshot of the website (to demonstrate what you are asking for) instead of linking to it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use configurable product for this.